# Query by data already in the object

Tags: node.js, mongodb, aggregation-framework

I'm writing a query that gets data from "coll2" based on data that is inside "coll1".

Coll1 has the following data structure:

```
{
  "_id": "asdf",
  "name": "John",
  "bags": [
    {
       "type": "typ1",
       "size": "siz1"
    },
    {
       "type": "typ2",
       "size": "siz2"
    }
  ]
}
```

Coll2 has the following data structure:

```
{
  _id: "qwer",
  coll1Name: "John",
  types: ["typ1", "typ3"],
  sizes: ["siz1", "siz4"]
}
{
  _id: "zxcv",
  coll1Name: "John",
  types: ["typ2", "typ3"],
  sizes: ["siz1", "siz2"]
}
{
  _id: "fghj",
  coll1Name: "John",
  types: ["typ2", "typ3"],
  sizes: ["siz1", "siz4"]
}
```

I want to get all the documents in coll2 that have the same Type+Size combo as in coll1 using the `$lookup` stage of the aggregation pipeline. I understand that this can be achieved by using the `$lookup pipeline` and `$expr` but I cant seem to figure out how to dynamically make a query to pass into the `$match` stage.

The output I would like to get for the above data would be:

```
{
  _id: "qwer",
  coll1Name: "John",
  types: ["typ1", "typ3"],
  sizes: ["siz1", "siz4"]
}
{
  _id: "zxcv",
  coll1Name: "John",
  types: ["typ2", "typ3"],
  sizes: ["siz1", "siz2"]
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [$lookup](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/lookup/index.html) to get the data from `Col2`. Then you need to check if there's any element in `Col2` ([$anyElemenTrue](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/anyElementTrue/index.html)) that matches with `Col1`. [$map](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/map/index.html) and [$in](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/in/index.html) can be used here. Then you just need to [$unwind](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/unwind/index.html) and promote `Col2` to root level using [$replaceRoot](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/replaceRoot/index.html)

```
db.Col1.aggregate([
    {
        $lookup: {
            from: "Col2",
            localField: "name",
            foreignField: "coll1Name",
            as: "Col2"
        }
    },
    {
        $project: {
            Col2: {
                $filter: {
                    input: "$Col2",
                    as: "c2",
                    cond: {
                        $anyElementTrue: {
                            $map: {
                                input: "$bags",
                                as: "b",
                                in: {
                                    $and: [
                                        { $in: [ "$$b.type", "$$c2.types" ] },
                                        { $in: [ "$$b.size", "$$c2.sizes"  ] },
                                    ]
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    },
    {
        $unwind: "$Col2"
    },
    {
        $replaceRoot: {
            newRoot: "$Col2"
        }
    }
])
```

Comment: Thanks! This is a good solution albeit not the most efficient one. I was trying to get only the required documents instead of getting more than required and then filtering it.

Answer (score 1):

You are correct in your approach to use **[`$lookup`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/lookup/)** with the pipeline field to filter the input documents in the **[`$match`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/match/#pipe._S_match)** pipeline
The **[`$expr`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/expr/)** expression should typically follow

```
"$expr": { 
    "$and": [
        { "$eq": [ "$name",  "$$coll1_name" ] },
        { "$setEquals": [ "$bags.type", "$$types" ] },
        { "$setEquals": [ "$bags.size", "$$sizes" ] }
    ]
}
```

where the first match expression in the **[`$and`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/and/)** conditional `{ "$eq": [ "$name",  "$$coll1_name" ] }` checks to see if the `name` field in `coll1` collection matches the `coll1Name` field in the input documents from `coll2`.
Of course the fields from `coll2` should be defined in a variable in the pipeline with the `let` field for the **[`$lookup`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/lookup/)** pipeline to access them.

The other match filters are basically checking if the arrays are equal where `"$bags.type"` from `coll1` resolves to an array of `types` i.e. `[ "typ1", "typ3" ]` for example.

On getting the output field from **[`$lookup`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/lookup/)** which happens to be an array, you can filter the documents in `coll2` on that array field where there can be some empty lists as a resul of the above **[`$lookup`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/lookup/)** pipeline $match filter:

```
{ "$match": { "coll1Data.0": { "$exists": true } } }
```

Overall your aggregate pipeline operation would be as follows:

```
db.getCollection('coll2').aggregate([
    { "$lookup" : {
        "from": "coll1",
        "let": { "coll1_name": "$coll1Name", "types": "$types", "sizes": "$sizes" },
        "pipeline": [
            { "$match": { 
                "$expr": { 
                    "$and": [
                        { "$eq": [ "$name",  "$$coll1_name" ] },
                        { "$setEquals": [ "$bags.type", "$$types" ] },
                        { "$setEquals": [ "$bags.size", "$$sizes" ] }
                    ]
                }
            } }
        ],
        "as": "coll1Data"
    } },
    { "$match": { "coll1Data.0": { "$exists": true } } },
    { "$project": { "coll1Data": 0 } }
])
```

Comment: Thanks for the info! I'm trying to lookup coll2 from coll1 though.

Comment: No worries. It goes both ways with the lookup really but the output from the above pipeline matches with the expected/desired, unless of course you want to do some prior filtering in `coll1` which also can be done in the `$lookup` pipeline.